# When determining the position of the principal points of a lens system from $f=PF$, should one always go towards the lens system?

Tags: optics, lenses

for an optics lab, I need to determine the position of the cardinal points of a telephoto lens. I got the focal points determined experimentally, and the focal length of the system f=200mm, which was written on the lens. On the diagrams of textbooks I looked at, taking the focal length from the focal points towards the lens system will determine the position of the principal points (I hope this is clearly formulated).
However, if I do this with my lens, I end up with the principal planes being inverted, and within the lens, so that the rear principal point is closer to the front focal point, and the front principal point is closer to the rear focal point. This seems strange because then the focal length would not be the same anymore, since the definition I have is that it is the distance between the focal point and the *closest* principal point. And for a telephoto lens, both principal points should be in the object space, in front of the first component.

Might I miss out something with the sings of the focal lengths/the radii of curvature (since one has a positive and a negative component) so that the focal lengths should be taken in the same direction, towards the object space, to find the principal points?
Or might the positions of the focal points not be exactly right?

Answer (score 0):

You should always measure distance in the direction light is traveling, and treat the optical centre as the origin of a virtual coordinate system.

Comment: Okay, thank you, so f goes towards the lens from the focal point since light travels in that direction? And then since f=-f', the other one goes in the other direction.